# Java - Loop issues

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a program that has a 1 in 5 chance to be correct and until it's correct it keeps going. It then should go and print the information to a file, however when I try to run it, it wont seem to run the second loop however many times I ask it to with the scanner. I need everything inside of the while loop to go the same amount of times as the for loop because I'm going to take it and find the percent average of how many times it takes to get the 20%. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

edit - The input that I'm giving to be specific is the variable trials, when I initiate the program if I set it to 1000 I expect to see the for loop repeat the loop and everything inside of it 1000 times.

edit 2 - I wanted to add what it was I'm going of off, I'm doing a project and here are my guidelines to go off of:

1. Determine how many bottle caps each person has to open in order to find a winning cap.  (This represents one trial.)  Print this value to a text file.
2. Prompt the user for the number of trials.  Conduct at least 1000 trials.
3. Read back the data for all of the trials from the output file.
4. Calculate the average number of caps opened in order to win a prize.
5. Print the result to the screen.

   import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.io.File;
   public class BottleCapPrize
   {
       public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
   {

   ```
   PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("EBoost Chance.txt"));
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   Random rand = new Random();

   System.out.print("How many trials will you run? ");
   int trials = in.nextInt();
   int totalTrials = 0;

   int randomNum = 0;
   int winCounter = 0;
   int counter = 0;
   int bottleCap = 1;
   int max = 5;
   int min = 1;
   double percentage = 0.0;

   for (totalTrials = 0; totalTrials <= trials; totalTrials++)
   {
       counter = 0;
       winCounter = 0;
       while (randomNum != 1)
       {
           randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
           if (randomNum == 1)
           {
               winCounter++;
               counter++;
               outFile.println("You would win in " + counter + " bottles.");
           }
           else if (randomNum != 1)
           {
               counter++;
           }
       }
   }
   outFile.close ( );
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: Not a bad question. However, you need to be more specific about exactly what input you give the program, exactly what output it produces, and exactly what output you expect. These details will make it much easier to help you. Please edit the question to include them.

Comment: So you're saying that if the user enters 5 you want both the `for` loop and the `while` loop to run 5 times? Because right now the `while` loop runs until `randomNum` == 1 (within the first `for` loop iteration) then there's nothing left to do, so naturally the `for` loop will always only run once.

Comment: @Hack-R I wanted it so the for loop would run everything inside of it however many times I set trials variable to. I don't know what I would do to make it so randomNum == 1 wouldn't just stop after that. Sorry if I'm missing something very simple here I'm still getting introduced to java.

Comment: You need to reset randomNum within the for loop (just before the while loop).

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset `randomNum` every for loop iteration. Otherwise, the while loop will never be entered because `randomNum` will still equal `1` from the previous iteration.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("EBoost Chance.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("How many trials will you run? ");
        int trials = in.nextInt();
        int totalTrials = 0;

        int bottleCap = 1;
        int max = 5;
        int min = 1;
        double percentage = 0.0;

        for (totalTrials = 0; totalTrials <= trials; totalTrials++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int winCounter = 0;
            int randomNum = 0;     // this was moved from outside the for
            while (randomNum != 1)
            {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                if (randomNum == 1)
                {
                    winCounter++;
                    counter++;
                    outFile.println("You would win in " + counter + " bottles.");
                }
                else if (randomNum != 1)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```